# RedirectToAction with Parameter to a Post Action ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, controller, actionresult

How to redirect to the Post action having two with the same name.

I have tried the next returns:

```
return RedirectToAction("nameAction", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "nameController", action = "nameAction", variable }));

return Redirect("nameController/nameAction/" + variable.ToString());

return RedirectToAction("nameAction", "nameController", new { variable });

return nameAction(variable);
```

I'm in my action Update and after it finish reading the code i want it to redirect to my [HttpPost] Index action with a variable.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(int variables, int variables2, int etc...)
        {
          .......
return RedirectToAction("Index", "nameController", new { variable });
            }
        }
```

I have two Index action, one Post and one Get

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
...
        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int variable)
        {
            ...
        }
```

It is redirecting me to the Index, but not to the POST action.
PD: I'm getting my variable on the URL.

I would want it to enter the Index Post action, could someone guide me with what I'm missing.

Comment: redirects are to gets not posts

Comment: Hi Nkosi, Is there any other way to achieve what i need?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud define rout :
try this

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            ...
        }
```

and use like :

```
 return RedirectToAction("nameAction",  new { id=variable });
```